# Openssl sha1 length

Tags: linux, bash, openssl

Why after executing the command `openssl sha1 < /dev/null | wc --bytes` the output is 50? The output size of SHA-1 should have 160 bits what gives us 20 bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Why is the output of `openssl sha1 < /dev/null | wc --bytes` 50?*

```
$ openssl sha1 < /dev/null
(stdin)= da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

Because the 20 byte digest is prefixed by `(stdin)=` and is expressed in hex.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot that the complete string is passed to `wc`. This was one of the contest questions asked during the meeting with Google SREs and I have to admit that it was tricky :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the raw, unformatted bytes, pipe the hexadecimal-formatted output from OpenSSL to `xxd -r -p`, to convert that representation to raw bytes.

For example, to make a Base64-encoded SHA-1 digest of the string `foo`:

```
$ echo "foo" | openssl sha1 | xxd -r -p | base64
8dLS+STphqyG/fezbJS83zK+7BU=
```

Or to simply validate the message length:

```
$ echo "foo" | openssl sha1 | xxd -r -p | wc --bytes
20
```

Comment: `xxd` ain't working for me in 2023.   But `echo "foo" | openssl sha1 -binary | wc --bytes` does.